# How System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl calls OpenSSL functions?

Tags: c#, c++, .net-core, openssl

can anyone explain how package `System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl` ([github: dotnet/corefix](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl)) calls OpenSSL nanive functions? I can't find brige from .net C# to OpenSSL C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/Common/src/Interop/Unix/System.Security.Cryptography.Native

The code you link to references those interop classes, which pinvoke into this code here:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/Native/Unix/System.Security.Cryptography.Native

Which calls into OpenSSL.

Comment: When I install the nuget package System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl, how can I use the binaries to create an SSL certificate?

Answer (score 1):

The types in the directory you linked to are all `partial` classes. The [.csproj file](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/7622efd2dbd363a632e00b6b95be4d990ea125de/src/System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl/src/System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.csproj#L77) in that directory includes a large number of files from [elsewhere](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/7622efd2dbd363a632e00b6b95be4d990ea125de/src/Common/src/Interop/Unix/System.Security.Cryptography.Native) in the repo. These files contain most of the methods and  `[DllImport]` platform invoke declarations.

The referenced `CryptoNative` (`System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl`) library is a native shim found at [corefx/src/Native/Unix/System.Security.Cryptography.Native](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/0fbbb68a3f7be82d26e4b2dff5c25c192e3a2023/src/Native/Unix/System.Security.Cryptography.Native), and forwards the calls to the actual OpenSSL implementation.